# Why do some request payloads have unreadble characters?

Tags: ajax, networking, websocket, request

Here is the example of a request payload on a website I visited:
[image: request payload example]

Here is the response payload for another website, using websockets instead of a POST request:

[image: websocket response]

Why are the characters unreadable? How can I make the text readable?

Comment: Is the payload specified to be in clear text? It looks more like it's packed using some serializing library.

Comment: Read [RFC 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) for the WebSocket protocol. Client-to-server packets are **masked** for security (whether or not TLS is used). And in both directions, packets are also **framed** in a structured manner. So you will have to decode the masking and the framing to get at the actual data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How does the client read it and therefore act on it, if the instructions are masked?

Comment: @javedb the client masks the packets it sends to the server. The server does not mask the packets it sends to the client.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Understood. Although the 2nd screenshot is a response from the server, but it's still masked which is why I'm a little confused

Comment: @javedb the server's response is not masked. You can see clear text in it. It is simply framed inside a binary format. Did you read the RFC spec I linked to earlier?